# How can I send latitude and longitude to a server using TCP/IP in Android

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

This is my asyntask class in which I try to connect to a server and send the latitude and longitude to it.

```
public class MyClientTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
   MyClientTask() {}

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        Socket socket = null;
        try {
             socket = new Socket("107.170.21.173", 8000);
             OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
             out.write("latitute".getBytes());// sending the lat to server
             out.write("longitute".getBytes()); // sending the long to server
             InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
             int output=inputStream.read();
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e)    
             e.printStackTrace();
        response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
}
```

But I can not read the response from inputstream i.e. server. I read out for TCP/IP connections, but could not implement it in my code.

Comment: is your server sending back anything?

Comment: sir if i send hello to server the it will also return hello only

Comment: Have you coded it that way? Because. by default it will not return `hello` for a `hello` from client.

Comment: You should also post corresponding server code. And send a delimiter between lat and lon.

Comment: #Prerak i have coded in this way only,plz help how should i code so that i could get the hello  when i send the hello from our side.

Comment: # greenaaps  sir I read at many  places that server code should we presnt but sir ,server side coding will already be present to server side.then is it required to cod efrom my side also,if so then when should i call that class.

Comment: It will be useful if you use JSON for sending and receiving via socket.
For eg: {"latitude":"1.02511","longitude":"-1.1542121"}